# Prove some linear algebra equalities and how to geometric interpret them

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, real-numbers

> Let $\alpha,\beta \in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha + \beta = 1$ and $x,y,z \in V$ where $V$ is a vector space.
>
> Show that $$\|z-(\alpha x+\beta y)\|^2=\alpha\|z-x\|^2+\beta\|z-y\|^2-\alpha\beta \|x-y\|^2$$
>
> And geometric interpret the result for $\alpha =\beta=\frac 12$.
>
> Also show that: $\|x - y\|\|z\|\leq\|x-z\|\|y\|+\|z-y\|\|x\|$ and geometric interpret this.

Okay, I saw where I was doing wrong, but I still have trouble proving this, what I did so far:

$\langle \alpha(z-x)+\beta(z-y), \alpha(z-x)+\beta(z-y)\rangle=\langle\alpha(z-x),\alpha(z-x)\rangle+2\langle\alpha(z-x),\beta(z-y)\rangle+\langle\beta(z-y),\beta(z-y)\rangle=\alpha\|z-x\|^2+\beta\|z-y\|^2+2\alpha\beta\langle z-x,z-y\rangle.$

I still have problems for the last factor..

And for the second one, where should I start?

Comment: Your first _easily seen_ is wrong: you only have $\leq$, not $=$. (ps: do you know about `$\langle$` and `$\rangle$`?)

Comment: @Antoine the exercise in my book is $=$. And yes.

Comment: He’s talking about _your_ first equation, not the one in the problem.

Comment: @amd oh then why is it not as I say?

Comment: One of many counterexamples would be $\beta =\alpha = 1/2$ and $z = 0$ and $x = -y$.

Comment: @Antoine and how do I solve it then?

Comment: Another mistake: In general, $\langle a + b, a + b\rangle \neq \langle a, a\rangle + \langle b, b\rangle $. Go step by step and see.